# Use Swipe to use another IBaction (XCODE)

Tags: xcode, gestures

I'm building a music app for iOS right now, I have a button which is connected with an IBoutlet for Nextsong. For example. How can I use swipe as a button. So when Swiped, an IBoutlet is triggerd.

Is this possible? And how would this be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define a function `nextSong` then your button and the swipe gesture can call it, depending on which action the user makes.